# nftw: remove the directory content without removing the top dir itself

Tags: c, file, directory, rm

I developed a function to recursively remove a directory with `nftw()`:

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ftw.h>     /* for nftw() */

int unlink_cb(
    const char *fpath, const struct stat *sb, int typeflag, struct FTW *ftwbuf)
{
    if(typeflag != FTW_D) {
        return remove(fpath);
    }
    return 0;
}

int rm_rf(const char *path)
{
    return nftw(path,
                unlink_cb,
                64 /* number of simultaneously opened fds, up to OPEN_MAX */,
                FTW_DEPTH | FTW_PHYS);
}


int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    rm_rf("any");
}
```

this will remove the directory with its content. but I want to remove only the content without removing the top directory itself.

Are there a way to add some check to skipthe remove of the top dir?

Comment: Do not tag both C and C++ except when asking about differences or interactions between the two languages. Pick one tag and delete the other.

Comment: Does that really remove the ditectory? I mean, there's the condition `if(typeflag != FTW_D) {
        return remove(fpath);
    }`

Comment: @hyde: With `FTW_DEPTH` given, `nftw` traverses directories in post-order (necessary so directories can be removed, since their contents must be removed first), and the called routine is passed the type `FTW_DP` instead of `FTW_D`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the test `typeflag != FTW_D` is useless in this case because the `FTW_DEPTH` flag to `nftw` instructs it to traverse directories in post-order, and then `nftw` never passes the called routine the flag `FTW_D`, which indicates a directory being traversed in pre-order. For directories it is traversing in post-order, it passes `FTW_DP`.

You could change the test to `typeflag != FTW_DP`, and then the program would never remove any directory, so it would not remove the top directory of the tree.

However, to have the program remove all files and subdirectories except the top, you can use the level indicator in the `struct FTW` that is passed. The `level` member indicates the depth of the current object, zero for the top directory, one for objects in it, two for objects within those, and so on. So the test can be simply:

```
if (0 < ftwbuf->level)
    return remove(fpath);
```

Note that your program should use `#include <stdio.h>` to declare `remove`.

Comment: Thank you, good answer